# Noun, verb or adjective?

Tags: meaning, verbs, nouns

> Whirring loudly the time machine slowly rose from the cluttered workshop floor.

What is **whirring**? Noun or verb?

> Petrified, Edward hurriedly hid behind the oak trees as the piercing scream echoed menacingly through the eerie, abandoned house.

What is **petrified** and what is **abandoned**? Verbs or adjectives?

> Brightly, the full moon shone through the ancient woodland illuminating the tendrils of mist delicately swirling skywards.

What is **illuminating**? Noun or verb?

Comment: Hello, Silvia. There are three separate questions here. And I think they may all be duplicates.

Comment: "Whirling" can only be a verb since it is modified by the adverb "loudly" (adverbs do not (normally) modify nouns). "Petrified" is an adjective referring to "Edward". "Abandoned" is also an adjective, modifying the noun "house". "Illuminating" is clearly a verb since it has the direct object "the tendrils of mist delicately swirling skywards".

Comment: @BillJ How do H&P deal with the infamous "Brown's deftly painting his daughter is a delight to watch'? Quirk et al put it somewhere along a noun-verb gradience of _ing_-forms (though multiple gradiences might be a truer representation). I assume H&P, who don't like gradience models, rank one test / two tests above another here?

Comment: @BillJ But an adverb can modify an adjective. The participles asked about are being used as adjectives, not verbs.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Don't agree. "Whirring" denotes an action modified by the adverb "loudly" (cf. "The machine was whirring loudly"). It's not a "whirring loudly machine" -- there is a difference. And "illuminating" has a direct object so it can hardly be an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

They are all participles. A participle is a form of verb, and may function both "verb" and "adjective".

While **whirring** and **illuminating** are used as verb,  ***petrified*** and ***abandoned*** are used as adjective in your sentences.

***Abandoned*** is being used before the noun;  while "petrified" is the reduced form of "Edward (is/was/-) petrified ..." or "Something petrified Edward"

Please check [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv325.shtml) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle) Wikipedia page

Comment: I would re-phrase this to say that a participle is an inflected form of a verb that can be part of a verb phrase or can be used singly as a verb, adjective, or noun. In English only the past participle can be used singly as a verb.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "whirring loudly" is a reducción of an adjective clause. The original sentence probably was "the time machine, which was whirring loudly, slowly rose..."; when the adjective clause was reduced to a phrase, it was fronted to emphasize the " whirring loudly " action expressed In this participle, which is acting as an adjective modifying the noun "machine".

Comment: I fully agree with this answer. The verb in the first sentence is "rose." "Whirring" is a participial used as an adjective. In all the other examples the participles are used as adjectives.

Answer (score 0):

Whirring is an active participle used as an adjective modifying the noun "machine." But because it is derived from a verb, it can be modified by an adverb. Similar case happens with gerunds and infinitives; they can take their own objects, modifiers, subjects and complements; however, they don't work as verbs but as other parts of speech (as nouns in the case of gerunds; as nouns, adjectives and adverbs in the case of infinitives; and as adjectives in the case of participles. There are some linguists,though, who consider participles as adjectives and adverbs).

Comment: Did you intend this to be an edit to yesterday's answer?